# DateTimeFormatter.format with Continent/City

Tags: java, scala, date, datetime, datetime-format

In my program, I have a date and a date-pattern in a text file, and the pattern is used with the DateTimeFormatter to parse/format the date.

Until recently my date looked like this `01-01-18 00.00.00,00000000 +01:00` and the date-pattern like this `dd-MM-yy HH.mm.ss,SSSSSSSSS xxx`. At the beginning of my program I am parsing the date with the pattern to a ZonedDateTime and at the end I am formatting another ZonedDateTime and overwriting the date in the text file and they should always be in the same format, which was working with this pattern.

Now I want to change it to use `Europe/Berlin` instead of `+01:00`, so there won't be wrong calculations if CEST changes to CET.

So my new date looks like this `01-01-18 00.00.00,00000000 Europe/Berlin` and my date-pattern like this `dd-MM-yy HH.mm.ss,SSSSSSSSS z`.
Now parsing still works fine, but when I try to format my ZonedDateTime, the output always  ends with `CEST` instead of `Europe/Berlin`.

Now I'd like to know if there is any way to implement this (preferably without hacky workarounds) so that the formatted date ends with the Continent/City.

Comment: Any reason why you aren’t just using `ZonedDateTime.toString()` now that you are changing your format anyway? Easy, and would allow other tools that know ISO 8601 to parse most of the string. Defining your own format is ill-advised. Furthermore, at least for dates in the past the offset gives you an unambiguous point in time, so why did you want to change that in the first place? Finally you have heard of the millennium challenges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output the time zone as "Europe/Berlin", use `VV` pattern letters, for example:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS VV")
println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter))
// 2018-07-05 23:12:06.901 Europe/Paris
```

It also works backwards:

```
val date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-07-05 12:00:01.123 Europe/Paris", formatter)
println(date)
// 2018-07-05T12:00:01.123+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```